# Add whitespace to current line in vim

Tags: vim

I fairly often find myself in a situation like this:

[image: vim screenshot with cursor at start of line]

I'd like to start typing on the line on which my cursor is currently. However, in order to get to the correct indentation level, I'd have to press TAB several times.

Usually I'd press <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> (delete current line and insert a new one above the cursor), which resets my indentation position to the right place:

[image: vim screenshot with cursor at correct position]

But that seems like an odd way to go about adding the correct amount of whitespace.

Is there a better way that I'm overlooking?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5760/how-to-move-the-cursor-to-the-correct-indentation-level-without-quiting-insert-m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in normal mode, you can use <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> or its synonym <kbd>S</kbd>. If you are already in insert mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> is the default key for this, but that can be changed by altering `cinkeys` (see `:h cink` for details).

See also [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5760/how-to-move-the-cursor-to-the-correct-indentation-level-without-quiting-insert-m) on the [Vi/Vim stack](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "I use cc. May be a "hack" but I doubt you'll find something shorter." You've outdone yourself.

Comment: Indeed, vim never ceases to amaze.

Comment: Do you mean in normal mode?

Answer (score 0):

Kevin mentioned some shortcuts, but another method is `<C-i>` (indent) and `<C-d>` (dedent) in insert mode.